# AJAX to Sharepoint Server with Phonegap and JQuery Mobile not working

Tags: android, sharepoint, jquery, cordova, https

I have the following Problem. In the Phonegap App(for Android) I want to make an AJAX-Call to connect with a Sharepoint Server, with the following Code:

```
 $.ajax({  
   url:"https://xxx/_vti_bin/lists.asmx",

   beforeSend: function( xhr ){
    xhr.setRequestHeader(
    "SOAPAction",
    "http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/GetListCollection"
    );
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","text/xml; charset=utf-8");
    }, 
   dataType:"xml",  
   contentType: "application/xml; charset=utf-8", 
   timeout:10000,  
   type:'POST', 
   cache: false,
   username: "username",
   password: "password",
   data: soapEnv,
   success:function(data) {
       // alert data
       var serializer = new XMLSerializer();
        serialized = serializer.serializeToString(data);
       alert(serialized);
   },  
   error:function(XMLHttpRequest,textStatus, errorThrown) {   
       // alert errors
     alert("Error status :"+textStatus);  
     alert("Error type :"+errorThrown);  
     alert("Error message :"+XMLHttpRequest.responseXML); 
     alert("Error statustext :"+XMLHttpRequest.statusText); 
     alert("Error request status :"+XMLHttpRequest.status); 
   }, 
   complete: function(jqXHR, textStatus){
       alert(textStatus);
   }
    });
```

When I try to run it on the Android Emulator the error messages are:

```
Error status: error   
Error type: 
Error message: undefined
Error statustext: error
Error request status: 0
```

However when I try to run it on my Browser (Chrome) with disabled websecurity (because of same origin policy) it works all fine. Phonegap normally shouldn't care about SOP because of the file:/// Protocol. I added the following to 'mobileinit':

```
$(document).bind("mobileinit", function() {
            $.support.cors = true;
            $.mobile.allowCrossDomainPages = true;
        });
```

But when I run the same Code in Chrome without websecurity disabled, I get exactly the same errors as in the Android Emulator.

I also tried an AJAX call to wikipedia (with html instead of xml, and GET instead of POST), and that worked without a problem.

Also I think the AJAX to Sharepoint doesn't even get fired (no traffic in Fiddler2, if I managed to configure it the right way)

So I am really stuck with this problem since 2 days now, if anyone knows how to make this ajax call work, it would made me so happy :-)

(soapEnv is the XML envelope, sent to the server)

Comment: Hi, were you able to solve this? Hope you can share your solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well I know that once upon a time jQuery had a bug where it treated a request status of 0 as an error. When running from the file protocol a status of 0 is the same this as a 200 (OK). You may need to update your version of jQuery.

Alternatively to test my theory just do a plain vanilla XHR request to your service to see if it works. Here is my stock example:

http://simonmacdonald.blogspot.com/2011/12/on-third-day-of-phonegapping-getting.html

Comment: Okay, thank you. I have already JQuery version 1.7. But I will try this plain  XHR request, too :-)